# Possibility to debug both HTTP and HTTPS in Kestrel and .NET Core like in .Net 4.x under IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I need to debug external authentication and it requires HTTPS. At the same time for most internal requests http is enough. There was no problem to listen on 80 and 443 ports when hosting my web app on IIS, but with ASP.NET Core hosted by Kesterl as I see it, the port is strictly bind to specific configuration in launchSettings.json such as:

```
"localCalls": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40000"
    },
"externalIdentity": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:50000"
    }
```

I'm curiuse, is it possible to have listeners on both ports at a time without necessarity to relaunch in the other configuration to change the protocol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#endpoint-configuration) you can define the endpoints within the same configuration:

```js
"localCalls": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
            "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5000;https://localhost:5100"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Asp.Net Core 2.1 and onwards makes it super easy to use local SSL. When you create the project using Visual Studio, it asks you if you need to enable the SSL or not. If you selected that option before creating the project, you should see your launchSettings.json file something like below:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61110",
      "sslPort": 44377
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "YourProjectName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

The `iisSettings` section is for IISExpress with an `sslPort` defined i.e. 44377 in this case. So when your project runs under IISExpress, it uses that settings

The `YourProjectName` section is for Kestrel. You can see that `applicationUrl` is using both `http` and `https` endpoints. So when you do `dotnet run` you should see

```
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\users\...\YourProjectName
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

In addition, under `Configure` method, you should see a line below, so it will automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

If your `launchSettings.json` file doesn't look like the above. Try changing it in the project properties and enable the SSL, like in the screenshot below. When you save the settings, the `launchSettings.json` file will be updated

[image]

If the above doesn't work, try changing the `launchSettings.json` file manually. I hope that helps

Comment: oh, thank you! there are too many ways to configure it! just after reading your two answers, found a perfect article, describing all in one: https://riptutorial.com/asp-net-core/example/7433/kestrel--configuring-listening-address